# How to query in linq using orderbydescending?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to query data, where the result is in descending order. 
When I query --

```
StartDate=04/09/2014&EndDate=04/16/2014,
```

I get results showing from the 9th instead the 16th. I am little unclear how is this achievable.  This is what I currently have:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
            var data = db.data_bd.AsQueryable();

            int pageSize = 10;

            if (query.price_type != null)
            {
                data = data.Where(c => c.Cover == query.price_type);
            }
            if (query.endDate != null)
            {
                data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate);
            }

            if (query.startDate != null)
            {
                data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
            }


            // If any other filters are specified, return records which match any of them:
            var filteredData = new List<IQueryable<data_bd>>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
            {
                var ids = query.name.Split(',');
                foreach (string i in ids)
                {
                    filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(i)));
                }
            }

            if (filteredData.Count != 0)
            {
                data = filteredData.Aggregate(Queryable.Union);
            }

            if (!data.Any())
            {
                var message = string.Format("No data was found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }

            if (query.startDate != null)
            {
               data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate).Take(pageSize);

            }

            if (filteredData.Count != 0)
            {
                data = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.UploadDate).Take(pageSize);
            }

            //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }
```

Am I missing something? Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're a little bit off here. First of all, if you reorder the list 4 times, the first 3 will have been a waste of time. I'm not sure what your logic is there, so I'll leave it at that. You need to rethink your filtering logic.

Secondly, the `Func` that you pass to `OrderByDescending` gets the *key* to order by; it *doesn't* perform filtering. So when you do:

```
data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate)
```

You are using a key of `true` if your upload date is after the query start date and `false` if  it's before the query start date. So you're going to get all of the `true`s followed by all of the `false`s. You're not ordering by date at all.

To order by *date*, you need to do something like this:

```
data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate)
```

This selects all of the items where the upload date is after the query start date and *then* orders them by `UploadDate`.

My advice would be to apply each of your filters first using `Where` and then do your ordering at the end by doing `OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate)` (or whatever property you plan to order by).

Comment: Hi, Many thanks, for your thorough explantion and help.  I manage to update the code, using the suggestion posted on this thread, but I have a small issue, with count variable count.  if possible, could you provide some advice or feedback on this matter. Please see the above updated code.

Comment: @user3070072 This sounds like a separate problem. If so, you should post a new question; otherwise this Q&A will become ambiguous and confusing for future users.

Answer (score 3):

You're not ordering by dates.. you're ordering by a boolean expression.

```
data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate).Take(pageSize);
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ bool
```

I can't quite understand what you're trying to achieve there.. but that's your issue. If you can expand a little more I can help further.

Comment: hi, I am trying to sort by UploadDate using a descending order regardless of which selection criteria is used. If I add orderby at the end of the where clause, this then conflicts with the above count variable. The count variable is used to count the query's query records before the 'Take(10)'.  Please advice, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this

```
data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate).OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably trying to filter between those dates and then order by descending date. Try this:

```
       if (query.endDate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate).Take(pageSize);
        }

        if (query.startDate != null)
        {
           data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate).Take(pageSize);

        }

        data = data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);
```